# Can't assign variable value with Cloud Firestore query in Invertase's React Native Firebase

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

## Context:

I am working on React Native project using [the RNFirebase starter project](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase). I have a collection `users` in Firestone. Every document in this collection has a field `username`. I want to display the logged in user's username in the home screen of my project. Thus far, I've figured out how to query for `username` in `users` using [this example from the official Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document).

## **First issue**:

Within the body of the query, I can (for some obscure reason) successfully `alert()` the value of `username` using the reference of the document I want. I want to store the value of this query into `currentUsername` and then render it, and this is the part that fails.

## **Second issue**:

After integrating the example code from the Firebase docs, my app also crashes after I call `signOut()`. The error is `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating _reactNativeFirebase.default.auth().currentUser.uid)`. If I remove the example code, `signOut()` works normally.

```
...

import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

...

export class Activity extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
        this.handleLogout = this.handleLogout.bind(this);
        this.state = { currentUser: null, errorMessage: null };
    }

    componentDidMount()
    {
        const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
        this.setState({ currentUser });
    }

    handleLogout()
    {
        firebase.auth().signOut()
          .then(() => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Login'); // This part fails as well
          })
          .catch(error => {
            this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message });
          });
    }

    render()
    {
        const { currentUser } = this.state;
        const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);

        let currentUsername = '';

        usersRef.get().then(doc =>
        {
            if (doc.exists)
            {
                currentUsername = doc.data().username; // This value does not persist
                currentUsername = (' ' + doc.data().username).slice(1); // I'm trying to deep copy it here, and that still fails
                alert("Current username is: " + currentUsername); // This does work, however
            }
            else
            {
                alert("No such document!");
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            alert("Error getting document:", error);
        });

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>
                    Hi @{currentUser && currentUsername}! // Renders nothing
                </Text>
                <Button title="Logout" onPress={this.handleLogout} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```